# Check specific hour

Tags: c#, date, timer

I've searched here for a solution, but I can't make it work for me.

My problem is:

I have a rotine where a email is sent each 2 minutes, but now I need to check the hour to send this email only once for day.

I need something like this

```
if(hourNow == '18')
  send();
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `DateTime` type has an `Hour` property that returns the hour of the day (0 - 23). You can use that:

```
if(DateTime.Now.Hour == 18)
    send();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var nowHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;

if(nowHour==18)
{
}
```

`DateTime.Now` gets current date and time, and `.Hour` get hour. You can do this with `Day`, `Year`, `Month` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) to get the current date and time, and then the [`Hour`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.hour.aspx) property to get the current hour of the day:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 18)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (System.DateTime.Now.Hour == 18)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 18)
{
    // Code Here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var nowHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;

if(nowHour==18)
{
}
```

DateTime.Now gets current date and time, and .Hour get hour. You can do this with Day, Year, Month etc.